Puppeteer bot works locally but fails to click button Kubernetes
I have a Teams meeting bot using Puppeteer that works perfectly fine locally but fails when deployed to Kubernetes. The bot get stuck and can not click on the button even though it found that button.
Quesitons:

What could cause this behavior difference between local and Kubernetes environments?

Are there specific Puppeteer configurations needed for Kubernetes deployments?

Could this be related to network idle or page load states?


Code Structure:
class Task {
  async initMeeting() {
    const { meetingUrl, userName } = this.taskData;

    await this.page.goto(meetingUrl, {
      waitUntil: 'load',
      timeout: 0,
    });


    await this.enterUserNameAndJoin(userName);
  }
   
    async ensurePageReloaded() {
        await Promise.all([
          this.page.reload(),
          waitForNetworkIdle(this.page, 1_000, 2),
        ]);
      }

    
  async enterUserNameAndJoin(userName) {
    const nameToType = `${userName}'s Assistant`;
    const selector = '[data-tid="prejoin-display-name-input"]';
    
    await this.page.waitForSelector(selector, {
      visible: true,
      timeout: 10000
    });

    await typeInput(this.page, {
      value: nameToType,
      dataTid: 'prejoin-display-name-input',
    });

    await this.page.waitForTimeout(1000);
    await clickButton(this.page, { ariaLabel: 'Join now' });
  }

}

My waitForNetWorkIdle
const waitForNetworkIdle = (page, timeout, maxInflightRequests = 0) => {
  page.on('request', onRequestStarted);
  page.on('requestfinished', onRequestFinished);
  page.on('requestfailed', onRequestFinished);

  let inflight = 0;
  let fulfill;
  let promise = new Promise((x) => (fulfill = x));
  let timeoutId = setTimeout(onTimeoutDone, timeout);
  return promise;

  function onTimeoutDone() {
    page.removeListener('request', onRequestStarted);
    page.removeListener('requestfinished', onRequestFinished);
    page.removeListener('requestfailed', onRequestFinished);
    fulfill();
  }

  function onRequestStarted() {
    ++inflight;
    if (inflight > maxInflightRequests) clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  }

  function onRequestFinished() {
    if (inflight === 0) return;
    --inflight;
    if (inflight === maxInflightRequests)
      timeoutId = setTimeout(onTimeoutDone, timeout);
  }
};

What I've Tried:
Increased timeouts
Added delays between actions
Verified network connectivity
Checked for element visibility

Its highly possible your ip is getting blocked by meeting.

But I can run it on local? And it direct into the correct url, the UI open, but it just cannot click the button.
